# Why does my styling completely break when I change .html file extension to .php

Tags: php, html, css

I need to include some php code on my contact form page so I tried changing the file extension from .html to .php and either my css page no longer connects or the html isn't even displaying properly. When open in a web browser only the lines of code (of the new php doc) as typed appear. Before changing the extension everything is styled and layed-out correctly, only changing the extension completely breaks it. Why is this? and how do I fix it?

Comment: You are running a web server, right? Not just opening the file in your browser.

Comment: How are you hosting the file

Answer (score 0):

Create a new php file and copy the content from that page to the new file and see if it works

Comment: tried making a new .php file and copying the content. does not even open

Comment: show the full content. might be some error there

Answer (score 0):

fix: I had a firewall blocking my localhost server when I tried opening the website folder. I just needed to whitelist the port. Thanks for the suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in chrome and here is how i fixed it:

**Setting > Privacy and security > Clear browsing data > select cookies and other site datas also cached images and files**

just in case also **turn off all the servers in XAMPP** before you do all this and turn it on again after clearing the data and then try to check if everything is working normal and if your problem is fixed!